Fixed Effects Panel Data Models with Multiply Imputed Data
I used the mice package to create 5 implicates of a dataset. I am interested in using fixest:feols() to estimate a fixed effects model that looks like this
m1 <- with(mi_data,
                 fixest::feols(outcome ~ treatment | hhid, data.frame(mget(ls()))))

m1_pooled <- pool(m1)
summary(m1_pooled, conf.int=TRUE)

However, I am having trouble pooling the estimates. I get the following warning message:
Warning messages:
1: The `exponentiate` argument is not supported in the `tidy()` method for `fixest` objects and will be ignored. 
2: The `exponentiate` argument is not supported in the `tidy()` method for `fixest` objects and will be ignored. 
3: The `exponentiate` argument is not supported in the `tidy()` method for `fixest` objects and will be ignored. 
4: The `exponentiate` argument is not supported in the `tidy()` method for `fixest` objects and will be ignored. 
5: The `exponentiate` argument is not supported in the `tidy()` method for `fixest` objects and will be ignored.

I found a related post that was helpful for the first step: Is it possible to use lqmm with a mira object? . It is is why I have data.frame(mget(ls())) in my data argument.
@David Thiessen came up with the answer. Unless I misunderstood, in another related post, he says that the pool() function should work well after including data.frame(mget(ls())) in the data argument.
Using mice for panel data models
In that post, the user uses plm to estimate the FE model, so I tried the same but obtained the same warning message as above:
m1 <- with(mi_data,
                 plm::plm(outcome ~ treatment, 
                          index=c("hhid"), 
                          data= data.frame(mget(ls())),
                          model = "within",
                          effect = "individual"))


m1_pooled <- pool(m1)
summary(m1_pooled, conf.int=TRUE)

In the first link, David is responding to someone using lqmm and mentions the trouble with trying to use pool() even after including data.frame(mget(ls())).  In turn, he creates two functions to try to address this issue:
tidy.lqmm <- function(x, conf.int = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, ...) {
  broom:::as_tidy_tibble(data.frame(
    estimate = coef(x),
    std.error = sqrt(
      diag(summary(x, covariance = TRUE, 
                   R = 50)$Cov[names(coef(x)),
                               names(coef(x))]))))
}
glance.lqmm <- function(x, ...) {
  broom:::as_glance_tibble(
    logLik = as.numeric(stats::logLik(x)),
    df.residual = summary(x, R = 2)$rdf,
    nobs = stats::nobs(x),
    na_types = "rii")
}

However, to be frank, I am not really sure how to use them. Though David created them for an lqmm model, it seems like they should work on both plm() and feols() output. However, when I try them, I get the following warning/error messages
> tidy.lqmm(np_hs_ad, TRUE)
# A tibble: 0 × 0
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `Cov`. 

> glance.lqmm(m1)
Error in UseMethod("logLik") :
no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "c('mimira', 'mira')"

I would very much appreciate any help trying to navigate this issue.
